# Add delete button for every row in datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

how to add a delete button for every row in a data grid (contains two fields) in WPF. while datagrid itemsource is

```
ObservableCollection<Result>
```

and

```
 public class Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Result(string name, string id)
    {
        this.FriendlyName = name;
        this.Id = id;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 28):

You can add a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and add a `Button` to its `CellTemplate`. Then use the built in `ApplicationCommands.Delete` or your own `ICommand` for the `Button`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FriendlyName"
                            Binding="{Binding FriendlyName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                            Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Delete"
                            Command="Delete"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Update**
If you don't want to use the built in `Delete` you can use your own `ICommand`. Here is a short example with `RelayCommand` which can be found in the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. Also, I uploaded it here: [RelayCommand.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1xa115pcd68rcx/RelayCommand.cs?dl=0)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- ... -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Delete"
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                              Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in your viewmodel or code behind

```
private Result m_selectedResult;
public Result SelectedResult
{
    get { return m_selectedResult;}
    set
    {
        m_selectedResult = value;                
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedResult");
    }
}

private bool CanDelete
{
    get { return SelectedResult != null; }
}

private ICommand m_deleteCommand;
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (m_deleteCommand == null)
        {
            m_deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Delete((Result)param), param => CanDelete);
        }
        return m_deleteCommand;
    }
}

private void Delete(Result result)
{
    Results.Remove(result);
}
```

Comment: thanks for updating by adding the `ICommand` way of deleting.

Comment: @Fredrik Hedblad , and how to delete item from .mdf database using this button `Content="Delete"
                            Command="Delete"`

Comment: And make sure the specify the datagrid in the xaml as CanUserDeleteRows="True" and IsReadOnly="False". I forgot these two.